# Include html page in thymeleaf

Tags: thymeleaf

I have 2 HTML files, suppose one.html and two.html. In one.html I want to include two.html.

In JSF I can do it like that:

It means that inside one.xhtml file, I can include two.xhtml.

How can we do it in *.html file? in thymeleaf

Comment: I think you'll have to use a template engine like jade, ectjs, doT...

Comment: i am new to thymeleaf ..i donno how to add template..?

Comment: Is it java or node.js?

Comment: instead of jsp..we are using thymeleaf for spring project

Comment: so why tag node.js then ?

Answer (score 3):

you can do it easily. could you share your `header.html` file?

or, let me show a bit like I do for my projects

in `header.html` put in side the `<body>` a code:

```
<div th:fragment="client_header">
    <p>This is for client</p>
</div>

<div th:fragment="admin_header">
    <p>This is for admin</p>
</div>
```

and let's say you want to add `client_header` into the `index.html`. Do follow these in your `index.html` page (inside `<body>`)

```
<div th:replace="includes/header :: client_header">
</div>
```

note: `includes/header` before `::` refers the html path (excludes `.html`) and `client_header` after `::` refers the part in `header.html` you want to insert.

I hope you understand everything that I have explain here.

Answer (score 1):

In one.html you can include two.html by following this steps:

1. Place both pages under the resources folder, something like /resources/one.html, /resources/two.html
2. Include two.html in one.html by adding this line in one.html:
   `<div th:insert="two :: two"></div>`
3. Include this bit of code in two.html just after the `<body>` tag:
   `<div th:fragment="two">`

This should include the bit of code surrended by the `<div th:fragment="two">`into one.html

More info in the [thymeleaf documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html)