# How to include one html page to another in thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have the following project structure in Spring Boot Application - 

/templates/home/index.html

/templates/includes/header.html

I want to include the header file inside the index file. 
I have tried the link - 
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538693/include-html-page-in-thymeleaf#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23538693/include-html-page-in-thymeleaf#_=_)

But the colon '::' is showing error.

I am new to thymeleaf. Can anybody explain? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please add index.html and exact error stack trace

Comment: Thanks.  I solved the problem. The code is as below - 
`
//header.html
<div th:fragment="header">
<!-- related code of header file >
</div>
<!-- related code of header file >



//index.html
//to include header follow the code( the header file is inside includes directory) 
<div th:replace="/includes/header :: header"> </div>
`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thanks all who tried to help me. 
I solved the problem as follows -

```
//header.html
<div th:fragment="header">
<!-- related code of header file >
</div>



//index.html
//to include header follow the code( the header file is inside includes directory) 
<div th:replace="/includes/header :: header"> </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do it easily. could you share your 'header.html' file?

or, let me show a bit like I do for my projects

in 'header.html' put in side the  a code:

This is for client

This is for admin

and let's say you want to add 'client_header' into the 'index.html'. Do follow these in your 'index.html' page (inside )

note: 'includes/header' before '::' refers the html path (excludes '.html') and 'client_header' after '::' refers the part in 'header.html' you want to insert.

I hope you understand everything that I have explain here.